# How to float/flex divs vertically then continue horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have a layout that gets customized by many different clients so the html structure is locked down to

```
<div class="container">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** not using bootstrap, container is just the applicable name

In the UI I need to be able to use CSS to make many different layouts from this structure without altering it. There is one in particular I can't figure out. The desired layout is this:

[image]

I know that if it were all vertical it would be easily doo-able with simple `width` and `float` styles. I also know that throwing a containing div around the first two children would be an easy solution but again requirements are to leave the html unchanged.

I've tried:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
    width: 33.33335;
    height: 400px;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
    height: 200px;
}
```

setting appropriate heights to the child divs where the first two are half the height of the others.

Similarly, I've tried:

```
.container > div {
    float: left;
}

.container > div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
    height: 200px;
}
```

and again giving the first two children a height that is half the others. Nothing has worked, in all outcomes either the first two stack and the others do not float/flex up or the the first two do not stack at all.

Can anyone figure a CSS method of styling this structure for the desired UI?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can set a fixed height on the container, you can use flexbox with `flex-flow: column wrap`. The fixed height is necessary to tell flex items where to wrap. Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; /* vertical alignment */
  align-content: center;         /* horizontal alignment */
  height: 320px;                 /* essential for this method to work */
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 0 0 90%;                 /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container>div:nth-child(1),
.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 40%;              /* override flex-basis from rule above */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for